# how to access element from a window (popup) in tinymce 4.x

Tags: javascript, iframe, tinymce-4

I have written a plugin for tinymce which opens a popup that gets loaded by url (it is creating the popup as an iframe). When I click on a button in this window, I want to access an element value from this popup (this element is an anchor tag which has url for an image) and load that as an image in the tinymce editor. How can I do this?

My plugin code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('fileuploader', function(editor, url) {

    editor.addButton('fileuploader', {
        text: 'Upload Image',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            // Open window with a specific url
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Upload Image',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/upload-file',
                width: 500,
                height: 100,
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Done',
                    onclick: function(e) {
                        editor.insertContent('Title: ' + document.getElementById("fileUrl"));
                        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tinymce 4.x has a builder mechanism for easily accessible dialogs ("body" setting in open(), currently very barely documented). http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### From the iframe, use `top` to access parent frame

You're already doing this to close the window:

```
top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
```

So, you should be able to use the same pattern to update the active editor in the parent window:

```
top.tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent();
```

Here is a basic example showing how you could get the `href` attribute from your `a` tag and use it to build an `img` tag that you can insert into the parent window's active editor:

```
...
buttons: [{
    text: 'Done',
    onclick: function(e) {
        var fileURL = document.getElementById("fileUrl").href,
            imgHTML = '<img src="' + fileURL + '" />';

        top.tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent(imgHTML);
        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    }
}]
...
```

Though inserting content is not explicitly described by the [TinyMCE documentation on "Creating custom dialogs"](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_custom_dialogs), it is implied with the example showing how to access `activeEditor` in the top frame using the native [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) property.

Also worth noting is that `window.top` has *read-only* [cross-origin access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access). To have *read/write* access, you will have to comply with [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Worked like charm. I was struggling to find answer and made a lots of efforts. Save me.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have jQuery loaded to simplify the code

The event object (`e`) contains a property `currentTarget` which is a reference on the popup opened.

This popup contains an iframe with the page you opend in it. We can find it with jQuery : 

`var frame = $(e.currentTarget).find("iframe").get(0)`

This line will return the Dom dom object of the iframe

Then you want to access the content of your iframe : 

`var content = frame.contentDocument`

(Be careful when doing this you must follow the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy))

Now you just have to find the element you need : 

`var result =$(content).find("#theElementINeed")`

I hope it helped you

Comment: I don't think that `e.currentTarget` will be a reference to the popup; it should be a reference to the DOM element bound to the event listener, which in this case is likely the `button`. Really, you can skip that step and just find the `iframe` by its `id` or its container's `id` (provided you know it): `var frame = $('#popup iframe').get(0)`

Comment: I would not have posted code that don't work. Try it on your own ;)

Comment: Touché. I'll take your word for it.